# In Ajax, How can i re-search the first search table?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I want to search MySQL db by Ajax. 
But the result table has so many records. 
So I want to filter the result table by re-search the first search result table.

Below code is my db.html(file name) code.

```
 <script>
  function showUser(str){
 if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
 }
 var selectedLang = document.getElementById('lang').value;

 xmlhttp.open("GET","db_"+selectedLang+".php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <select name="lang" id="lang" size="2" style="width:99px;">
   <option value="co">한국어</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>

    <option value="af">Afrikaans</option>
   </select>
   <form>
   <input type="text" name="FirstName" maxlength="20" onkeyup="showUser(this.value)">
    <br>
   <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>
```

And my php code is below. Please read that

```
    <?php
    $q = htmlspecialchars($_GET['q']);
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','autoset','my_db');
    if (!$con)
    {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM persons WHERE FirstName = '".$q."' or LastName = '".$q."'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    echo "<table border='1'>
     <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Hometown</th>
     <th>Job</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);

    include 'db.html';
    ?>
```

But, This php code "include 'db.html'" doesn't work as i think. 
And
Q1. i cannot hold the first search result, so 
Q2. I cannot re-search the first search result.

How can i overcome this 2 problems??
Please, help me!

Answer (score 0):

Create a session when you make your ajax call. In that session store the DB connection handle. When you do your query, save the result in a temporary table. Then when you do each search, look for the temp table first. If it exists, search in there first and resave the results in another temp table. Either discard the first or not depending on user feedback.

Repeat this until you have the result set you want.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But kindly, please, let me show example code.